# Subtract a value from a field on database

Tags: php, sql, pdo

i have a problem where i want so subtract 1 value from a field on my table when i add a regestry.

I have 2 tables

Livros

- CodLivro
- Nome
- Total

and

Vendidos

- CodVenda
- CodLivro
- Nome

Lets imagine the total is 20, when i sell a book i want to remove one value from that field.

the current code is

```
 case "vender_l":
{
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO Vendidos (CodLivro, Nome) VALUES (:CodLivro, :Nome)");
    $stmt->bindParam(':CodLivro', $CodLivro);
    $stmt->bindParam(':Nome', $Nome);


    break;
}
```

Comment: *when i sell a book i want to remove one value from that field.*   **Hint** Update

Comment: When a book is sold you need to minus quantity.. ie  update stock set quantity = quantity - 1 where id = sold book AND quantity >= 0

Comment: "Lets imagine the total is 20, when i sell a book i want to remove one value from that field." This might make sense to someone also speaking the language the table and column names are in, but absolutely none for those who don't speak the language. Please edit your question bearing that in mind.

Comment: and how can i subtract a value fom that total? is there a function that will do it

Comment: There is the `-` operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the comment from Masivuye Cokile is right...

Let's put the names of your tables and columns in the example:

```
update Livros 
set total = total - 1
where codLivro = 10 -- 10 is an example of a book id  
  and total > 0     -- prevents the number of books from being negative
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this code, it should work.

```
UPDATE Livros SET Total = Total-1 WHERE Livros.CodLivro = :CodLivro;
```